# Bitrix Не могу найти исходник закодированного поля в почтовом шаблоне

Tags: php, битрикс

Не могу найти исходник закодированного поля с префиксом в почтовом шаблоне формата #BASKET#, просто хочу поменять то что он выводит.
Для поиска использовал команду grep по всему серверу и со всеми регистрами, но нужных результатов не нашёл, файлов init.php вообще нет.
Такой вопрос где вообще в теории можно найти эту несчастную #BASKET#?

Comment: Почтовый шаблон же в БД хранится?

Comment: Находите почтовый шаблон, смотрите тип почтового события, по нему ищите вызов почтового события, а в момент вызова передаётся массив с 'BASKET' => ..., там и меняете.
В почтовом шаблоне #BASKET# или #ASD# просто слова можно любые делать, а значения передаются в массиве при вызове события.
Искать такое если https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cevent/send.php если событие падает ещё в таблицу БД b_event.
А если не падает в БД то такое https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cevent/sendimmediate.php . (а если это что то штатное, наверно копать в сторону перехвата событий)